# Short story in which computers make everything for humans, but refuse to make a model train kit

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Computers make everything for humans. Guy gets a model train set made. Next, the guy wants a train kit and the computers refuse, because he would be creating something.

Short story found in a late 70's high school sci-fi text book, I believe.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I think this could well be *[Rat Race](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?41020)*, a short story by Raymond F. Jones, originally published in 1966.

An excellent summary is available from the Mporcious [blog](https://mporcius.blogspot.com/2021/03/social-science-fiction-by-harry.html). The main points are:

> "Rat Race" is set in one of those utopian futures in which robots and
> computers do all the work so people have nothing to do and find that a
> life without goals or obstacles is unfulfilling.  George Sims-Howton
> is one such unfulfilled man...  He stumbles upon references to model
> trains, how popular they were among men and boys like 150 years ago,
> and conceives a desire to have his own elaborate model railroad, a
> contagious fascination that has soon spread to his friends.  By
> feeding old plans they find into the computer that efficiently runs
> the world economy, they are soon provided with an abundance of
> engines, cars, track, scale buildings, etc

This comes to an end however, when he requests a lathe and sheet metal to make his own models - people are forbidden from doing creative work, except for "a narrow elite". The complete story can be read in the April 1966 copy of *Analog*, available, for example, at the [Luminist archive](https://s3.us-west-1.wasabisys.com/luminist/SF/AN/AN_1966_04.pdf).

It has not been republished widely, but indeed appeared in a school textbook edited by Bernard Hollister entitled *[You and Science Fiction](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?55764)*

Comment: Nice story! But compare the alternative vision of _With Folded Hands_ ...

Comment: Wow! I will check it - sounds about right though ... not too many scifi stories about model trains ;)